# Dedicated AppPool still unloads AppDomain after about 10 minutes

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-8

I have an application that is experiencing some really long warm up periods as long as 15 seconds or so. A warmed instance performs business logic and responds in ~150ms over the internet. This was initially part a shared AppPool with 34 other applications. I isolated it to its own but this still occurs. It used ninject which I removed as I've seen extremely high CPU spikes on other apps with it but am still seeing this behavior. My standard configuration for AppPools is so:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value "v4.0"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name startMode -Value "AlwaysRunning"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name processModel.idleTimeout -Value ([TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(0))
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value ([TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(0))
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{Value="04:00"}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name cpu.limit -Value 50000
Set-ItemProperty -Path $newPool.PSPath -Name cpu.action -Value "ThrottleUnderLoad"
```

I'm not sure what else to do outside of an active heartbeat check every minute or so which I really want to avoid. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that the AppDomain is unloading after 10 minutes?   Is it performance based?   Any entries in the Windows Event Log?   Are you able to reproduce the issue in a test environment?   If so, can you implement some ApplicationEnd logic to log the shutdown reason?   Very old sample code here: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194

Comment: @Rich-Lang you are correct that I didn't actually observe the AppDomain being unloaded. I added the logging you linked to and nothing appeared on any of my nodes. Unfortunately, now I'm at more of a loss. This might have to go on the back burner until something more concrete arises. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Have you tried setting the application pool to always on? This would be in the AppPool advanced Settings

Comment: @mahlatse that is what the `startMode -Value "AlwaysRunning"` line in the above is for

Comment: I see, didnt check that line, have you tried enabling wcf logs? all of them as a drastic  measure, also do a performance counter and check if that might highlight anything that might be going wrong on your service